# Adjacency list tree - how to prevent circular references?

Tags: sql, mysql, circular-reference, adjacency-list

I have an adjacency list in a database with ID and ParentID to represent a tree structure:

```
-a
--b
---c
-d
--e
```

Of course in a record the ParentID should never be the same as ID, but I also have to prevent circular references to prevent an endless loop. These circular references could in theory involve more than 2 records.  ( a->b, b->c, c->a   , etc.)

For each record I store the paths in a string column like this :

```
a    a
b    a/b
c    a/b/c
d    d
e    d/e
```

My question is now :
when inserting/updating, is there a way to check if a circular reference would occur?

*I should add that I know all about the nested set model, etc. I chose the adjacency method with stored path's because I find it much more intuitive. I got it working with triggers and a separate paths-table, and it works like a charm, except for the possible circular references.*

Comment: I solved it for now, by keeping track of the used ID's in the recursive path-loop. When it sees an ID that was already used, it inserts 'NULL' instead of the ID.  Maybe not very elegant but it seems to work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're storing the path like that, you could put in a check that the path does not contain the id.

Comment: That's what I realized, first I was storing the used ID's in a separate array, but while building the path, I could just use the path-string itself to check the ID against :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Oracle you can implement a check for cycles using the CONNECT BY syntax.  The count of nodes should be equal to the count of decendents from the root node.

```
CHECK (
(SELECT COUNT(*) Nodes
 FROM Tree) =
(SELECT COUNT(*) Decendents
 FROM Tree
 START WITH parent_node IS NULL -- Root Node
 CONNECT BY parent_node = PRIOR child_node))
```

Note, you will still need other checks to enforce the tree.  IE

Single root node with null.
Node can have exactly one parent.

You cannot create a check constraint with a subquery, so this will need to go to a view or trigger.