# Self-referencing table with parent-child relationship to represent file tree using LINQ

Tags: c#, database, linq, sql-server-2008, linq-to-entities

I have a single database table representing a file tree structure.

```
Files
- Id (int, primary key)
- Name
- ParentId (int, foreign key to Files.Id)
```

How can I write a method that makes sure all parents of a child cannot have the child's Id as its ParentId to prevent a infinite loop when displaying the tree structure.

Also, is there a more efficient way to design this?

Update:
I use sql server 2008 which supports hierarchy id, would that be helpful? (I'm not sure if EF supports it)

Comment: You could potentially add a value that is "level" and then you simply need to make sure that no node has a parent that has a level that is greater than or equal to its own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could potentially add a value that is "level" and then you simply need to make sure that no node has a parent that has a level that is greater than or equal to its own.  When you add the nodes, you would set the new child node to parent node level + 1.

Cheers

Comment: I don't think this would work when merging two trees. eg: there are two independent trees. I attach the first node of tree A to an end node of tree B. this is a valid use case but would fail your test.

Comment: To represent files, I don't believe that is a good use case.  The hierarchy would wither be copies or moved, and then the levels would need to be reassigned.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how you could write this efficiently with LINQ - you would have to make too much database queries. Instead, you should consider writing a stored procedure to check it on database side.

Alternative approach could be for each element to store not only ID of parent, but the whole hierarchy path from root element all the way down to itself - see [example of this in related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5056655/adjacency-list-tree-how-to-prevent-circular-references). Then, your job would only consist of checking whether the path does not contain two identical IDs and reject elements with such a path - this could be done either with a trigger on database side, or some validator in your application.

**EDIT:**

Regarding the HierarchyId - it seems to be no built-in way to work with it in Entity Framework, at least not until .NET 4.5. You may want to check out [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3347860/is-there-a-practical-way-to-use-the-hierarchyid-datatype-in-entity-framework-4) - it contains a custom implementation that should enable you to use HierarchyId in Entity Framework.

Comment: that could cause other problems. what if the parentId gets changed? then it would have to update all the hierarchy in all related entries

Comment: @James Yes, you are right, that can be problematic. On the other hand, displaying the tree gets really simple - all information is already at your disposal.